# CF9 and twitter bootstrap 3.2.0 - checkbox buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion-9

I am trying to get the newest Twitter Bootsrtap checkbox buttons working with Coldfusion 9. The code I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div id="flatsearchform-roomscount" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="3">3</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="4">4</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="5">5</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="6">6</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="7">7</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="8">8</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="9">9</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox" value="10">10</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I run this code on my local computer, it renders correctly and the checkboxes are buttons [image: (Capture1)]. 
But when I run the same code on the Coldfusion server, it displays incorrectly, with the checkboxes still being checkboxes [image: (Capture2)]. 
Has anyone gotten this working?

Comment: (Edit) I am not familiar with bootstrap, but it sounds like a simple JS/CSS problem, nothing to do with CF. For example, that might happen if the browser could not load the jquery.min.js script. Silly question, but are you testing with the same code and browser?

Comment: The two files are identical. I tried both in firefox and chrome and had the same issue in both. The remote environment is windows server 2008. my local environment is windows 7. All the included files are sites, so it's not a difference in the css....

Comment: (Edit) Only thing I can think of is to check your browser's JS debugging tools to verify the css and js are actually being loaded.. Like I mentioned, you would get the incorrect display if the browser was not able to load one of the files, like jquery.min.js., for some reason. For example, I can reproduce the "incorrect" display above by using adblocker to simulate a failure to load `jquery.min.js`.